# Highlighting the array of code lines in PHP

Tags: php

I have an associative array in which every single value contains one single line of code. I display them in the `foreach()` loop. How can I highlight all of them?

I've found the `highlight_string()` function. It does work, yes, but only with PHP tags surrounding the code. The problem is that I don't want to display these tags. It's an array, so the tags should be added to every single value which would make the outcome looks ugly.

Adding tags to the beginning and the end of the array doesn't work either - I won't use `highlight_string()` on the whole array (surrounging `foreach()` loop).

And if I get rid of the PHP tags, highlighting stops working.

Is there any way to do this without including 3rd party applications?

EXAMPLE:

This is the array:

```
$var = array(0 => 'for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)', 1 => '// do something', 2 => '$i++', 3 => '}');
```

This is how I display lines of code one after another:

```
foreach($var as $line) 
{
   echo $line . '<br>';
}
```

And I want to display them as the highlighted code.

Comment: Can you show us little sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will hopefully be of assistance here:

```
$code_array = array(
    '<?php',
    'echo "Hello";',
    '?>'
);

echo highlight_string(implode("\r\n", $code_array), TRUE);
```

Addition: Since you added your code sample this will work too :)

```
$var = array(0 => 'for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)', 1 => '// do something', 2 => '$i++', 3 => '}');
$var = array_merge(array('<?php'), $var, array('?>'));
echo highlight_string(implode("\r\n", $var), TRUE);
```

Comment: *cough* Don't forget to accept your favorite answer *sneeze cough*

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/). It is used by many websites and open source projects.

Comment: Thanks, but my intention was to create the whole project from the white screen without adding ANY external code... :P